# How to create a loading bar in java

Tags: java, swing, components, progress-bar

I want to know that how to set a loop for a progress bar when i clicked a button. 
I have tried it with a loop but it was a waste of time.I have attached the picture below that i exactly want.[There is button in the North of the form and there is Progress Bar in the south](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHcx3.jpg)

Comment: First of all you need to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) article. Then you need to create your dialog for progress, transfer it to your SwingWorker and update them when propgress changed.

Comment: can you give code of what you tried so far?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressBarDemoProject/src/components/ProgressBarDemo.java) is a good example, but without dialog.

Comment: @chanisajayawardana What do you mean by `how to set a loop for a progress bar` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here is a simple example of progress bar that progresses when you hover over the Button (Based on your picture) and you can do your background stuffs within the thread once the Mouse is over the button :-

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class GUI extends JFrame 
{
boolean isMouseOver = false;
int count = 0;

public GUI()
{
    this.setTitle("Progress Bar");
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 407, 119);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setBounds(10, 45, 371, 22);
    this.getContentPane().add(progressBar);

    JButton btnMousOver = new JButton("Mouse Over");
    btnMousOver.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt)
        {
            isMouseOver = true;
            btnMousOver.setEnabled(false);
            Thread go = new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    while (isMouseOver && count < 101)
                    {
                        count = count + 2;
                        progressBar.setValue(count);
                        // do some stuffs here
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            go.start();

        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt)
        {
            isMouseOver = false;
            btnMousOver.setEnabled(true);
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mouse CLicked");
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mouse released");
        }
    });
    btnMousOver.setBounds(142, 11, 108, 23);

    this.getContentPane().add(btnMousOver);
    this.getContentPane().add(progressBar);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new GUI();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Null saint...it worked perfectly.. :)

Comment: Can i know one small thing. I want to increase the value of the progress by 2 when i goes over "Mouse over" Button .Every time i goes over the mouse it increased by 2.

Comment: @chanisajayawardana then instead of count++ make it count = count +2 count is the incrementation

Comment: i mean i want to incresed the progreess bar by 2 but it shoud stop when i put the pointer away....again i goes over the button it should increase by 2...

Comment: I have already do it...i want to know hot to increase and stop the loading when i put pointer away from the button.

Comment: ok ..its working correctly..Thank you very much for spending your valuable time for me. :)

Comment: No probs @chanisajayawardana